# KVM disabled by BIOS

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, lvm

When starting my Linux laptop I see KVM disabled by BIOS. What does this mean for encryption and security? There is no virtualizarion option in the BIOS. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When starting my Linux laptop I see KVM disabled by BIOS.

KVM in this context stands for “Kernel Based Virtual Machine” and [as this page explains](http://www.linux-kvm.org/):

> KVM (for Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a full virtualization
>   solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization
>   extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V). It consists of a loadable kernel
>   module, kvm.ko, that provides the core virtualization infrastructure
>   and a processor specific module, kvm-intel.ko or kvm-amd.ko. KVM also
>   requires a modified QEMU although work is underway to get the required
>   changes upstream.
>
> Using KVM, one can run multiple virtual machines running unmodified
>   Linux or Windows images. Each virtual machine has private virtualized
>   hardware: a network card, disk, graphics adapter, etc.

Or as [Wikipedia more succinctly states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine):

> KVM (Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a virtualization infrastructure
>   for the Linux kernel that turns it into a hypervisor, which was merged
>   into the Linux kernel mainline in February 2007.

That said you ask specifically:

> What does this mean for encryption and security?

100% nothing. KVM is strictly functionality in the Linux kernel related to potentially allowing your system to be a hypervisor (aka: virtualization host). So even if your computer could be a hypervisor with the use of KVM even *that* would have 100% no impact on encryption and security.